# How to keep element in viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html element which is displayed when a button is clicked. It‘s kinda like a popup. I want to check if it’s in the ViewPort of the browser and then place it inside the ViewPort . Is there a right way to achieve that?

At the moment I’m checking the height of the ViewPort and compare it to the point where the element will be attached to. So I do something like this:

```
If(window.innerHeight > yPointWhereElementIsAttachedTo + heightOfElement) //attach element;
```

But what is the right way to do it?

Comment: please provide the code of your example, you say you have the html element, make a code section showing your html element.  when you say you "do something like this" please show you do that something like this

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using `position: fixed;` on an element with positioning.

For example:

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  left: 10px;
  top: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed">
    I am fixed in the viewport
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use scrollIntoView() if a more dynamic approach is required.

```
 var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
 elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp